# why discord db is not being created with my docker-compose.yaml file

Tags: database, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  discord-backend-service:
    build:
      context: ./../discord-backend/
      dockerfile: ./../discord-backend/discord.dockerfile
    ports:
      - 9001:9001
    restart: always
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
    container_name: my-discord-backend-service
    environment:
      - MONGO_URI=mongodb://imran:Dil%402580123@mongo:27017
      - PORT=9001
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  mongo:
    image: 'mongo:latest'
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: --bind_ip_all
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: imran
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: Dil@2580123
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: discord
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb_data_container:/data/db
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
volumes:
  mongodb_data_container:
```

I am not able to see the discord db, why?